# What kinds of formal logic have applications in law?

Tags: theory-of-law

There are different kinds of formal logic: propositional, first order, second order, modal, fuzzy, .... What kinds of formal logic have applications in law? Thanks.

Comment: None whatsoever. You might find a passing reference to Aristotelian syllogisms.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I think this is a perfect question about law. It is actually somewhat a disturbing revelation that logic has no place in law — contrary to what many lay people may think.

Answer (score 5):

> The Life of the Law Has Not Been Logic; It Has Been Experience.

-- Oliver Wendell Holmes, Jr.

Basically none.

Answer (score 3):

> The common law is tolerant of much illogicality, especially on the surface; but no system of law can be workable if it has not got logic at the root of it.

(Lord Devlin, Hedley Byrne & Co., Ltd v Heller & Partners [1964] AC 465, 516)

To think like a lawyer, you need to use [three](https://www.deakin.edu.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0005/728105/du-legalreason.pdf) types of logical reasoning:

- [reasoning by analogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_analogy),
- [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_reasoning), and
- [deductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_reasoning)

However, the standard required is not rigorous logical proof, it is reasonableness. That is, on the evidence provided, is it open to a reasonable person to draw the conclusions that the decision maker made.

Answer (score -4):

The words Blackacre and Greenacre and the like, used in the way lawyers use them, are examples of what mathematical logicians call "bound variables."

Comment: "*I wonder whether there may be some reason for the downvotes here other than ignorance of logic among those learned in law? Can someone explain?*" I did not downvote, but I am explaining [some issues](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1753/18505) with this answer.